# Assigning a form and params to struts 2 action in s:a tag

Tags: html, struts2

I am currently working on a project of migrating an application in struts 1 to struts 2. I have few problems which I couldn't find the solution yet.

1.In struts 1 we can assign a form to each action in strus-config XML. But in struts 2 I don't see that option. A form with submit button will automatically create a form in the action class. But how about an action from a link? I have a link(using s:a tag) from which I call an action which goes a to a jsp with the search form. But in the call from the link(s:a), I couldn't get a form in the action class. I need to set few values in the search form before it loads. Is there a way where a form can be assigned to an action without having s:form tag in the JSP?

2. Send parameters through s:a

I have the below which I am able to send parameters to a call

```
<s:a onclick="pleaseWait()" action="action1" >
<s:param name="param1"><s:property value="#request.paramValue1" /></s:param>
<s:param name="param2"><s:property value="#request.paramValue2"/>/s:param>  
Some Link
</s:a>
```

But is there any simpler way to assign params to an action without using a lot of s:params and s:property tag? Using some script to create a map which can be directly assigned to the action

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set in the action. What is the problem?

Comment: "Set in the action" you mean to set the form as action class variable? If yes I did have the form set in Action but when I try to use it it comes as null.

Comment: jQuery can serialize a form to a string of delimited params. but you're right, maybe it's nice that Struts can do it.